# How Can I access a property of an object array set in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building my first react app for my final react course on scrimba and I am retrieving data from an API and setting a part of the data to an array set in state, but I cant seem to access a property of the array

```js
import React from 'react'

const [request, setRequest] = React.useState([])
 
        
React.useEffect (() => {
        fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setRequest(data.results.map(({ question, correct_answer, incorrect_answers }) => ({question, correct_answer, incorrect_answers}))))
    }, [])


console.log(request[0]) // returns the first object array
console.log(request[0]["question"]) // gives an error
console.log(requst[0].question) // gives an error
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your `request` state value is an empty array when component mounts. So `request[0]` is `undefined`. So trying to log sub-properties of `undefined` will throw an error. If your state is gonna be some asynchronous value, like data fetched from an API, you have to handle that on mount it will be the initial state value

Comment: *"returns the first object array"* - Look more closely at what's logged to the console.  The *first time* that statement executes, it logs `undefined`.  (You can more effectively understand your logging output by logging meaningful strings with the value, for example: `console.log('First array element: ', request[0]);`)

Comment: @David, yes sir, the first time the statement executed it logs `undefined`, Is the problem coming from the dependency array or from the initial value of the `request`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I cant seem to access a property of the array

Sure you can, but *only when that array element exists*.  The initial state of the array is empty:

```
const [request, setRequest] = React.useState([])
```

An empty array has no elements, so this logs `undefined` to the console:

```
console.log(request[0])
```

And then this produces an error:

```
console.log(request[0]["question"])
```

And then this *does not* produce an error, because it isn't executed, because the line before it produced an error:

```
console.log(requst[0].question)
```

But if that line of code *was* executed, it too would produce an error.

---

The data you're fetching to populate state is coming from an asynchronous operation.  So it's going to happen at some later time.  (Could be milliseconds and *feel* instantaneous, but still some later time.)

Until that data has been fetched and until the state has been updated, the code needs to be able to handle the initial state of the empty array.  [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is one option:

```
console.log(requst[0]?.question)
```

Or perhaps wrapping the whole thing in a conditional:

```
if (request.length > 0) {
  console.log(request[0]);
  console.log(request[0]["question"]);
  console.log(requst[0].question);
}
```

How you prefer to handle an empty array is up to you and the logic you're implementing.  But the point is that since you define an empty array, the code should expect to start with an empty array.

Comment: The Conditional method worked for me, Thank you so much sir

Answer (score 1):

Setting data inside `request` state takes time. So you always get `undefined` for the first log of `console.log(request[0])` and error for other two console.logs.
In that case, you can check by using `UseEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(request.length === 0) return;
  console.log(request[0]); // returns the first object array
  console.log(request[0]['question']); 
  console.log(requst[0].question); 
}, [request]);
```

If you don't want to use `useEffect`, you can use `?` to access object properties without error.

```
console.log(request[0]);
console.log(requst[0]?.question);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (request !== undefined && request.length > 0) {
    console.log(request[0])
    console.log(request[0]["question"]) 
    console.log(request[0].question) 
}
```